# sin (x) + cos (x) = 0. Why this equation has only one solution set?

Tags: trigonometry

The equation "sin (x) + cos (x) = 0" has only one solution set "$x=\frac{3\pi }{4}+\pi n$".

Why it has not solution set "$x=\frac{7\pi }{4}+\pi n$"? Although it satisfy the equation.

Please help quickly.

Comment: That is the same solution set.

Comment: I am guessing that your request "help quickly" will not get you many helpful answers... Maybe try to be more patient and understand that we are not here at your service may get you more help...

Comment: $7\pi/4-3\pi/ 4=4\pi/4=\pi=n\pi$ with $n=1$.

Comment: *every* equation "has only one solution set."

Answer (score 2):

The equation is  equivalent to
$$\tan x=-1$$ since the two functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ don't vanish together so we find
$$x\equiv\frac{3\pi}4\mod \pi$$

Comment: I am not sure how this addresses OP's concern.

Answer (score 2):

A solution set is a set of points that satisfies a given equation.  A given equation will have only one solution set.  That set can have many descriptions.  $\frac {3\pi}4+n\pi$ is one description of the solution set for this equation.  $\frac {7\pi}4+m\pi$ is another description of the same set.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\frac{7\pi}{4} + n\pi = \left(1 + \frac34\right)\pi + n\pi = \frac{3\pi}{4} + (n+1)\pi,$$
so you are naming the same set of solutions but with a different indexing system.